# Replace string in JPG image

Tags: python

I have some images that I import from an android phone and when trying to open on PC, I couldn't open it properly. I could solve the problem by opening the image by notepad++ amd modify part `ICC_PROFILE` to `ICC_PROFILX`
I tried this python snippet but the image destroyed

```
with open("Sample.jpg") as r:
  text = r.read().replace("ICC_PROFILE", "ICC_PROFILX")
with open("Sample.jpg", "w") as w:
  w.write(text)
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Can you share the image also?

Comment: Can you also try this `with open("Sample.jpg",'rb') as r:`

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` whne using `rb`

Comment: Images are binary files, you need to use `'b'` mode to open them. This means you'll read bytes instead of strings, which also means you need to replace bytes: `.replace(b'ICC_PROFILE', b'ICC_PROFILX')`.

Comment: Here's sample file at this link (compressed file) https://www.mediafire.com/file/3jawaez6qev8ci6/SampleFile.zip/file

Comment: @deceze Thanks a lot. I tried your suggestion and got an error `TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not bytes`

Comment: Can you try this? `text = r.read().decode(encoding='ISO-8859-1').replace("ICC_PROFILE", "ICC_PROFILX")`

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: use `rb` as reading type

Comment: Now the error changed `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Can you try changing encoding types to different types like `utf-8, utf-16`?

Comment: I tried both utf-8 and utf-16 and the same problem persists. Can you please try the sample file I have uploaded?

Comment: @PrakashDahal Please don't pursue this idea; it's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG is a binary format; you need to read (`"rb"`) and write (`"wb"`) as binary to avoid corruption, and then pass `bytes` (`b"..."`) in both the arguments to the `.replace` method.

```
with open("Sample.jpg", "rb") as r:
  text = r.read().replace(b"ICC_PROFILE", b"ICC_PROFILX")
with open("Sample.jpg", "wb") as w:
  w.write(text)
```

If the replacement is not exactly the same length as the original, you will corrupt the file for other reasons. In fact, a much better solution is to use a dedicated image library which understands the `JPEG` format, but for really simple things, you can occasionally get away without one.

When reading and writing text, Python transparently normalizes line endings, so you can't know if the input file contained `\n` or `\r\n`. There are also other corner cases where the internal Unicode representation may not always round-trip back to exactly the original sequence of bytes. If what you are reading isn't actually text, always use binary mode.